# Why SimpleForm doesnt work with date field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, date, simple-form

I am using lasted `simple_form` gem and following simple_form form render error:

`` cant`t convert Symbol into String ``

[image]

```
= simple_form_for @student, html: { multipart: true, class: 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
  = f.input :email, disabled: true
  = f.input :birthdate
  = f.input :address_number
  = f.input :address_street
  = f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary pull-right"

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: students
#
#  address_number          :string(255)
#  address_postalcode      :string(255)
#  address_street          :string(255)
#  approved                :boolean          default(FALSE), not null
#  ask_counter             :integer          default(0)
#  authentication_token    :string(255)
#  birthdate               :date
```

Here is `edit` view and `Student`: https://gist.github.com/ccbef8a0fb67a164efee

My Gemfile: https://gist.github.com/00ec5a897a6cb88e0bab

Issue on gem github page: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/695#issuecomment-10495237

Rails: `3.2.8`
SF: `2.0.3`

How to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for that issue is here:
https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/695#issuecomment-10495237